# Dark status bar icons after migrating to Flutter 2

Tags: android, flutter, statusbar, android-theme, flutter2.0

I have recently updated the Flutter version from 1.22.6 to 2.0.2. But now after I create a new flutter project (default counter app), the status bar icons are dark. They were light before migrating to 2.0.2:

[image]

How can it be fixed? I've tried to set the light statusBarIconBrightness in the AppBarTheme, but it doesn't work:

```
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should set `statusBarColor` too
for dart statusBarColor you should use bright colors for brightness

```
AppBarTheme(color: Colors.blue,
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: Colors.blue
                ))
```

Comment: Thank you. The "brightness: Brightness.dark" helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 return MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(
          appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark,),
       ...
     ),
     ...
 );
```